# PNG truecolor, 8 bit depth, how to read IDAT chunk

Tags: colors, png, rgb

I have a question regarding a PNG file that I am trying to read (I have attached it in this question) [image]

The file size 328750 bytes
Width 660
Height 330
Color type - truecolor
Bit depth - 24 bits

So here's my question. If it's true color, I assume it's RGB, which is 24 bits. But you do the math, the number doesn't add up. 660 (width) * 330 (height) * 3 bytes (from 24 bits) = 653400 bytes, which is double the actual file size.

Why is that?

I tried to read the IDAT chunk, pretending that each pixel is 3 bytes, and I tried to check the colour and it doesn't match what is displayed.

Comment: Please start with reading the [official specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/). These basic questions are all answered in there.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a compressed image format, so the IDAT chunk(s) contain a zlib-compressed representation of the RGB pixels.  Probably the easiest way for you to access the pixel data is to use a converter such as ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to decompress the image into the Netpbm "PPM" format.

```
 magick image.png image.ppm
```

or

```
 gm convert image.png image.ppm
```

Then read the "image.ppm" in the same way you tried to read the PNG.  Just skip over the short header, which in the case of your image is

```
P   6  \n   6   6   0       3   3   0  \n   2   5   5  \n
```

where "P6" is the magic number, 660 and 330 are the dimensions, and 255 is the image depth (maximum value for R,G,and B is 255, or 0xff).  The remainder of the file is just the R,G,B values you were expecting.